# Testing login page AngularJS with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying write e2e test for my login page. Is there any easy way to mocking my backend if I need get response with http status and username and token?

I have sth like this:

```
 $httpBackend.whenPOST(apiURL + '/security/login-processing').respond(function(){
      var data = {};
      data.authorization = '34f47d42-d8b8-44c1-9a99-bf667d2203ec';
      data.username = 'admin';
      return data;
    });
```

But it doesn't work correctly..

Comment: take a look at the docs here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend
they have an example to address what you are looking for.